# Ionic 5 Post request adding extra params when params are in JSON

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, http-post

Here is a snippet of my POST request:

```
this.http.post(SERVER_URL + '/jobs', data, {headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': res, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})})
```

When sending to the API an extra parameter, job containing my parameters is being added:

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"title", "description"=>"desc", "min_salary"=>1, "max_salary"=>2, "job"=>{"title"=>"title", "description"=>"desc", "min_salary"=>1, "max_salary"=>2}}
```

I did a `console.log` before sending the POST request and the extra job parameter isn't there before the POST request.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is your main data and what is the part that contains the additional parameter?

Comment: @MostafaHarb  in the parameters an extra 'job' parameter containing my main parameters (title, description...) is being added

Comment: I think its a wting in your code , for example : const data = { title: 'title here', another: 1}; and this is normal , but in the output above its giving something like this : const data = { title: 'title here', another :1, job : data} . job property is binded again, if its re-added as you are saying , then the output should be const data = { job : {title :...}} but its not.